Screenshot using Puppeteer and AWS lambda
I want to take screenshot of website dynamically using AWS lambda.
When I tried to use pupperter-core it is showing below error
Error. Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
I am using node js version 20.
I tried pupperter-core v23.8.0 and 19.8.0
Tried chrome-aws-lambda 10.1.0 and
"@sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda": "^17.1.3",
"@sparticuz/chromium-min": "^131.0.0"
"@sparticuz/chromium": "^131.0.0"
But still I am not able to achieve screenshot functionality using Puppeteer and AWS lambda.
Please help me to achieve this functionality.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Same issue is solved and discussed here: /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Vercel.
There's many solution, so i do not know which one will fit on your case.
